# Renaming the package in AndroidManifest is not working

Tags: java, android, svn, android-manifest

I am trying to create 2 different apk's from the same project which will be installed in the same device simultaneously. I am doing this by changing the package name in AndroidManifest file and then renaming the relevant package. In normal case, this works fine.

But I have my project in SVN, I follow these steps,

1. Change the package name in AndroidManifest.xml file in all the applicable places.
2. Save, now press YES in the alert box.
3. Go to Project Explorer in eclipse, try to Refactor the package name. Now I end up with the following error in the photo below.

[image]

I am not getting what is this, because for the project which is not in SVN, I don't have any problem. So confused why I'm getting for the one in SVN.

**This is the error:**

```
    move /home/keerthiraj/Desktop/ICS/Project/src/com/ai2/ordershark /home/keerthiraj/Desktop/ICS/Project/src/com/hla/oshark


svn: '/home/keerthiraj/Desktop/ICS/Project/src/com/hla' is not a working copy
svn: '/home/keerthiraj/Desktop/ICS/Project/src/com/hla' is not a working copy
```

Can any body please suggest me something.

Comment: Open project into file explorer and check option "show hidden files" and delete the .svn files if there. I think you copied the project which was into the SVN.

Comment: @PankajKumar, I din't get your 2nd point. I have exported the project from SVN trunk only into my local workspace

Comment: The project for you are trying to rename package is the copy of the same project which was in SVN. right? Then simply delete the .svn files as I said.

Comment: @PankajKumar, I am sorry, I am in ubuntu. Can you guide me how to see those files? I tried here

Comment: I got it, there is a .svn folder in my project. You want me do delete that?

Comment: Yes delete those all .svn files. You will get this file into all each dir of project. So find carefully and delete them. BUT NOT IN THE MAIN PROJECT only from the project which is the copy.

Comment: there is .svn folder in each folder of the project. I think it will effect the svn connection if I delete that

Comment: :) What I said that? You must not do this into your original project. Copy the the original project into different location and then delete .svn files. I am not saying that do this into original one. \

Comment: I got it, but confused with Original word. What is the use then having 2 separate projects? Finally I want to commit this to the original svn project only

Comment: In current you have only one project into SVN? right? then this is the original project. And you have to create another repo for 2nd project into svn. SO don't worry about .svn files. Are you trying to change package name into the project which is into SVN? or you only want to change package name and create apk.

Comment: I will tell you in detail, I have a single Project in my SVN. I checked out that to my workspace. Now, I am trying to edit the package name of the project name which is in my local workspace. So, after editing I should be able to commit the changes to the one in SVN. Hope you got it.

Comment: So, what I am asking is if I delete those .svn folder from my project it will loose the connection with the SVN. So, the local project becomes isolated and I will end up in having 2 separate projects

Comment: Yes you are correct. Then only one way left is DON't do re-factor. You  need to create a project as you need. And move classes into that package (this will not cause the error then). now you need to change package statement of each file :(.

Comment: Then those files (into old package) will treated as deleted and into new package will treated as added.

Comment: You mean I have to create a new project just to change the build? Oh god! this is not possible. Because I will be doing this very frequently. For each build I cannot create a new project right

Comment: What do you think seeing the answer pratik wrote? Disconnecting the project from svn, I can refactor the package. But how to commit it back?

Comment: See, if you are curious about the history of project then its not possible. When you refactor the package you are going to loose your project history. Now, yes you can follow the steps which he gave. And commit the the code as you commited your fist commit of current project. Better is first create branch and copy your current project there, so you will have your current project too.

Answer (score 1):

here are the stepsto change Package name:

-> Right click on your project-> Go to Refactor-> Change package name-> Go to your main package-> Right click on it-> Change package name there-> Go to manifest file-> You can see main package name will be changed.

Comment: Refactor the Project or particular package name?

Comment: I did this, Right Click Main Package --> Refactor --> Changed name --> AndroidManifest is not updated.

Comment: Sorry I forgot one step. Right click on your project-> Go to Android Tools-> Rename Application Package.

Comment: I did this. I renamed Application Package. IT affected in Manifest file. But when I tried to refactor the package name in explorer, again the same error

Comment: Ok just for testing purpose, please disconnect your project from svn and then clean your project and try it.

Comment: Disconnect in the sense? A separate copy of the project?

Comment: Right click on project-> GO to team-> Disconnect

Comment: Disconnecting is working, but how to connect it back? I want to commit the changes to original SVN project

Comment: ok great, right click on project-> team-> share project-> select svn-> go through wizard.

And please right the answer, and upvote please.

Comment: I will try this and will tell you